# VMWare Server 2.0 auto start VM

Tags: vmware-server, virtualization, virtual-machines

I have a production server running vmware server 2.0.  I want one of the VM's (company intranet) to power on automatically if the host server is rebooted.  I searched online and found references to an autostart setting for the global configuration file and/or the local VMX files.  However in all cases, the advice was given 4 years ago, so I am not sure if this even applies anymore.  Should I just put a shortcut to the .vmx file in the startup group?  Is there a better/different way?  Thanks all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the VMWare Server GUI, select host in the "Inventory" panel (root node of the tree), to the right "Commands" panel should appear with "Edit Virtual Machine Startup/Shutdown Settings".  There will be an option to autostart the guest VM.

Comment: Its the one answer!

Comment: Totally missed the "root node" part of the UI - thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

under the inventory, highlight on the host name (physical machine name) not the VM that you want --> then from the right you will find (Edit Virtual Machine Startup/Shutdown Settings)
--> then Allow to start automatically

Thanks,
Mina

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately do not have a running VMWare console nearby, but there is a Startup and Shutdown either under the Virtual Machine menu or the virtual machine configuration. There is a simple tick box that specifies whether you want the machine to auto start, and you can also specify a delay. You can also control in which order the machines start.

This is standard functionality in VMWare Server.

(gsharper posts is more accurate regarding finding the option)